# Is there function to parse an IP address into 4 integers in iOS?

Tags: ios, parsing, networking

Something like `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")`?

Comment: Have you tried `inet_addr("127.0.0.1")`?

Comment: @RobNapier apparently inet_addr is deprecated and you should be using inet_pton instead.

Comment: Don't.  This will break for IPv6 addresses. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *ipAddress = [NSString stringWithString:@"127.0.0.1"];

NSArray *results = [ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([results count] == 4) {
    NSLog(@"1 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:0] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"2 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:1] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"3 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:2] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"4 - %d", [[results objectAtIndex:3] intValue]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"not valid ip");
}
```

Comment: "not valid ip"? What about IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling something like

```
 inet_pton(AF_INET, "239.255.255.250", &broadcastAddr.sin_addr);
```

you have to include

```
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: when you dig down into the sin_addr field in the inet.h file, all I can find is that it is backed by a 32 bit int.  I can't seem to find any macros that pull out the addresses components.  I'm sure they exist somewhere, but where?

Comment: I now think that there is no standard way to extract out the IP components from the sin_addr field.  And as per http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html he basically says "Here be dragons" if you try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably check out the [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i). If it is something simple you could just do something like

```
... [yourSting stringcomponetsSeparatedByString@"."]; //('formatting String Objects' section)
```

or you could do something envolving scanners from apple's sample code ('Scanners section') so that you can search through the relevant string for what you want:

```
NSString *string = @"Product: Acme Potato Peeler; Cost: 0.98 73\n\
Product: Chef Pierre Pasta Fork; Cost: 0.75 19\n\
Product: Chef Pierre Colander; Cost: 1.27 2\n";

NSCharacterSet *semicolonSet;
NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *PRODUCT = @"Product:";
NSString *COST = @"Cost:";
NSString *productName;
float productCost;

NSInteger productSold;
semicolonSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"];
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO)
{
if ([theScanner scanString:PRODUCT intoString:NULL] &&
[theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:semicolonSet
intoString:&productName] &&
[theScanner scanString:@";" intoString:NULL] &&
[theScanner scanString:COST intoString:NULL] &&
[theScanner scanFloat:&productCost] &&
[theScanner scanInteger:&productSold])
{
NSLog(@"Sales of %@: $%1.2f", productName, productCost * productSold);
}
}
```

Good Luck